# Play 2 Framework: start plugins before JPA startup to run liquibase migrations

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0, liquibase

I'm using a [liquibase plugin](https://github.com/CedricGatay/play-liquibase) for my Play 2.2.3 application, it works fine.

However I can not manage to make it together with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update` or `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate`, because JPA is always started earlier than the plugins. Thus first the update/validation by DDL is performed before the liquibase gets a chance to make changes.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable hbm2ddl if you are using Liquibase since it should be Liquibase's job to ensure your database is up to date.

Comment: Since Liquibase scripts are edited manually, there might be mistakes. I want ddl to check, whether Liquibase updated actually led to the correct data model.

Comment: @Alex did you figure out a solution?  I want to run evolutions before hibernate starts and validates

Comment: @poornerd I added a script to run liquibase update before the application starts, and used ddl=validate to make sure the integrity is not broken.

Comment: Thanks @Alex - I am trying to run the validation in the Global, but I am stuck getting the Hibernate Configuration. Maybe you have an idea?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/25871914/1808672?stw=2  I will post my solution if I can get it working ;-)